# Do Java standard libraries implement RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5 or AES Key Wrap?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa

Does one of Java's standard libraries supports the Content Encryption Key being encrypted using RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5 or AES Key Wrap?

I know for example that I can do

```
gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
gen.init(256);
SecretKey contentEncryptionKey = gen.generateKey();
```

but how do I get the `byte[]` array using standard libraries (no third party libs)

Comment: Gentlemen : Any comments on why 3 downvotes so far ?

Comment: Sorry, your question is not linked to your example. You are mixing a lot of things : RSAES stands for RSA Encryption Scheme and AES Key Wrap is a way to wrap (or, to explain it in a simple way, encrypt) a key with an other AES key. A better question could be "how to get my AES key binary representation)

Comment: @WhirlMind sorry : I forgot to hit the "add comment" button ;)

Answer (score 2):

`contentEncryptionKey.getEncoded()` will get you the encoded `byte[]` version of the key.